# C# Selenium Chrome Devtools Protocol

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

I am trying to use this devtools protcol command: `Page.AddScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument`.

It seems that this protocol command is not fully implemented in the [c# version of selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/DevTools/AutoGenerated/Page/AddScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocumentCommand.cs). I also tried [the click event](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/DevTools/AutoGenerated/Input/DispatchMouseEventCommand.cs) too, but this didn't work as well. However, I was able to use one devtools command, a networking one with the code:

```
IDevTools devTools = driver as IDevTools;
DevToolsSession session = devTools.CreateDevToolsSession();
session.Network.Enable(new OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.Network.EnableCommandSettings());
session.Network.SetBlockedURLs(new OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.Network.SetBlockedURLsCommandSettings()
{
    Urls = new string[] { "favicon" }
});
```

Is there something I can do to fix this myself?

References:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8000

Comment: It's implemented by the protocol itself which is why the cs file is just a dummy (same for the other commands), so I guess you've used it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code you can use:

```
using DevTools =  OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V95;

using Network = OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V95.Network;

using DevToolsSessionDomains = OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V95.DevToolsSessionDomains;


        IDevTools devTools = chromeDriver as IDevTools;
        IDevToolsSession session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();


        var domains = session.GetVersionSpecificDomains<DevToolsSessionDomains>();
        await domains.Network.Enable(new Network.EnableCommandSettings());
        await domains.Network.SetBlockedURLs(new DevTools.Network.SetBlockedURLsCommandSettings()
        {
            Urls = new string[] { "favicon" }
        });
```